# Approach on changing row color on orders grid in admin

Tags: magento, grid

I need to change row color in magento orders grid based on order status.
For start I don't want a complex solution with configurable interface.
I just want to know where to start.

What is the best approach ?

Comment: When I do this in dreamweaver , it complains of a syntax error on thee second line below, any ideas? } }); } document.observe("dom:loaded", colorize);

Comment: don't rely on dreamweaver. just use the code and see if browsers throw some errors or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Full, working solution:**

Copy `js/mage/adminhtml/grid.js` to `js/colors/adminhtml/grid.js`

Make the file 666 and the folders (js/colors & js/colors/adminhtml) 777.

Edit it and after line 208 *(before the line containing `}.bind(this)`)* add:

```
colorize();
```

At the end of the file add:

```
function colorize () {
    $$('td').each(function(macguffin) {
       if(macguffin.innerHTML.strip()=="Processing") macguffin.parentNode.setStyle({backgroundColor: 'Orange' });
        if(macguffin.innerHTML.strip()=="Pending") macguffin.parentNode.setStyle({backgroundColor: 'Gold', color:'Black' });
        if(macguffin.innerHTML.strip()=="Payment Review") macguffin.parentNode.setStyle({backgroundColor: 'LightPink' });
        if((macguffin.innerHTML.strip()=="On Hold")||(macguffin.innerHTML.strip()=="Payment Review")) macguffin.parentNode.setStyle({backgroundColor: 'HotPink' });
        if(macguffin.innerHTML.strip()=="Suspected Fraud") macguffin.parentNode.setStyle({backgroundColor: 'Red' });
        if((macguffin.innerHTML.strip()=="Closed")||(macguffin.innerHTML.strip()=="Canceled")||(macguffin.innerHTML.strip()=="Cancelled")) macguffin.parentNode.setStyle({backgroundColor: 'LightBlue', fontStyle: 'italic' });
        if(macguffin.innerHTML.strip()=="Complete") macguffin.parentNode.setStyle({backgroundColor: 'Green' });
  });
}
document.observe("dom:loaded", colorize);
```

Now create or edit the admin local.xml file in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/local.xml`

Edit it to include:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>mage/adminhtml/grid.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>colors/adminhtml/grid.js</name></action> 
    </reference>
  </default>
</layout>
```

The orders grid will now be in vibrant colours and you should be able to clearly see what orders need attention.

The `colorize()` function can be edited to suit your order states and preferred colour scheme.

Comment: I have removed some comments and put together a fully working solution that does not involve editing of core files, using a local.xml file and copy of the grid.js. With thanks to @Alan Storm

Comment: Thank mathew and @Alan Storm for a complete solution.

Comment: Just one syntex error is there. removing extra "}" placed before "});"

Comment: that's nice but i want the solution from block. anyone?

Comment: The Solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766173/magento-different-background-color-for-group-of-rows-on-backend-grid

Comment: This worked great, but it also affects the other grids. If you want to target just the sales order grid, be more specific with your selector: `$$('#sales_order_grid_table d').each(function(macguffin) {...`