# Magento: how do I over-ride an admin js file instead of editing it in core?

Tags: magento

Recently answered this question with a change to a core file:

[Approach on changing row color on orders grid in admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569386/approach-on-changing-row-color-on-orders-grid-in-admin/6570005#6570005)

There is one file that needed updating to answer this question: `js/mage/adminhtml/grid.js`

What I would like to know is how to do this properly, i.e. without editing the core file.

**Edit**

This is what worked:

in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/local.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>mage/adminhtml/grid.js</name></action>
        <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>colors/adminhtml/grid.js</name></action> 
    </reference>
  </default>
</layout>
```

Then I put a new directory + subdirectory and file in `js/colors/adminhtml/grid.js`

And many thanks to Alan for giving me the 'courage' to do it properly...

Comment: Keep in mind if Magento ever makes significant changes to grid.js your new version may end up incompatible (forcing you to switch back to the default version)

Comment: Will do, but I am pleased to have got to grips with local.xml and I am getting a bit nearer to not having to use mega meld/diff sessions whenever a new version comes out...

Comment: I suggest then to make some build scripts, so that your own grid.js is made from original one, with only color constants replaced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Add a Javascript Block to the Page, using events, the adminhtml application's local.xml, or a custom module layout xml file
2. Add a Prototype [dom:loaded event listener](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/document/observe) to the page
3. Using Prototype's `$$` method, search the dom for the order status HTML DOM nodes.  If possible, use an ID in there to ensure you're getting the right nodes.
4. Use Prototype's `addClassName` method to add a css class to the nodes from #3.
5. Add a CSS file to the page, using events, the adminhtml application's local.xml, or a custom module layout xml file.  In this CSS file add style definitions to get the colors you want.

Comment: I got there! Thank you so much.