# Magento, different background color for group of rows on backend grid

Tags: magento, grid, magento-1.7

On a backend admin page with a grid I need to change the background color for groups of rows. Not alternate color row by row as default but coloring groups according to a known column value.

I was looking into this SO question: [Approach on changing row color on orders grid in admin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6569386/1297603) and other similar pages. But can't reproduce what I need as this question refers to a value in a column that will be repeated.

I need to either use different colors for different groups or at least use alternate colors of those groups.

Maybe something like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to change the color of cell or for the entire row?

Comment: Entire group of rows that have a column with same value

Comment: I am not sure, that I got it at all. Would you add a graphic with explanation or may be to show just an example? Thanks.

Comment: Btw I am working on something similar an here is my progress so far: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0fcp2sn47

Comment: Well, could be something like that, will need to check it out. The SO I'm referring on my question does try to solve something like what you are doing. Will try to see on monday what can be done. I will use your screenshot to show an example of what I want, it's ok for you?

Comment: Sure :) Who knows, may be somebody will answer till Monday.

Comment: Yeap...is just that at home I do not have anything installed...you know, leave work at work ;)

Comment: Thanks for the visual ... Quick question: Is this for custom Magento module made by you or you have to do this for some of the existing grids in Magento admin area?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For anyone looking for a solution. I used this tutorial on the Inchoo website: [Add custom renderer for a custom column in Magento grid](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-add-custom-renderer-for-a-custom-column-in-magento-grid/). There are some SO questions that also helped to understand the solution.

I didn't manage to change the full row background color as initially wanted, I'm just modifying the cell background. But at the end, is enough to point the user that this row is somewhat different. What I have done was add a new custom column. On the `renderer` property I referenced a new class.

```
$this->addColumn('collision_type', array(
          'header'  => $helper->__('Collision'),
          'align'   => 'center',
          'index'   => 'collision_type',
          'type'    => 'action',
          'renderer'=> new Dts_Banners_Block_Adminhtml_Collisions_Grid_Renderer_Collisiontype(),
));
```

I placed the needed class inside a new subtree:

```
Grid
  └─ Renderer
        └─ Collisiontype.php
```

And this is the new class that should render the column. To have different colors just need to evaluate the `$value` variable and apply different color styles for the corresponding value, that is what I'm doing now.

```
<?php
class Dts_Banners_Block_Adminhtml_Collisions_Grid_Renderer_Collisiontype extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
        $value =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
        return '<div style="color:#FFF;font-weight:bold;background:#F55804;border-radius:8px;width:100%">'.$value.'</div>';
    }
}
?>
```

And the result:

[image: Screen shot of grid with rendered column]

Answer (score 1):

In my case i used above code snippet. I had need to create a custom radio column in grid for category. So i placed all conditions to this like this.

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
        $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
        $screenId = $category->getCategoryAttachedID();
        if($row->getId()==$screenId)$checked='checked="checked"';
        else $checked='';
        return '<input type="radio" name="screen_id" value="'.$row->getId().'" '.$checked.' >';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers above are good, but sometimes you want to do the same thing without creating a new file.
Here is another way to achieve the same result remaining in the grid file.

```
$this->addColumn('collision_type', array(
      'header'  => $helper->__('Collision'),
      'align'   => 'center',
      'index'   => 'collision_type',
      'type'    => 'action',
      'frame_callback' => [$this, '_formatCell']
));
```

then in the same file

```
public function _formatCell($value, Varien_Object $row, Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column $column)
{
    $value =  $row->getData($column->getIndex());
    return '<div style="color:#FFF;font-weight:bold;background:#F55804;border-radius:8px;width:100%">'.$value.'</div>';
}
```