# split columns into rows, not classical pivot

Tags: mysql

**EDIT:** asked on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157966/192104) and decided to modify my question, new additions in bold.

I have the following query, that finds overlapping periods of time:

```
SELECT t1.id1, t2.id1
  FROM `mytable` AS t1
  JOIN `mytable` AS t2
    ON (
        ((t1.start_date BETWEEN t2.start_date AND t2.end_date))
        OR ((t1.end_date BETWEEN t2.start_date AND t2.end_date))
       )
 WHERE t1.id1 < t2.id1;
```

The result set is:

```
id1    id1
 6      7
 8      9
 5      11
 10     12
```

I need the following result, just adding all the values on a single column, **and adding a column to show wich rows are pairs so later I can use that result [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13766173/1297603)**. Should be simple, but I can not get it working.

```
col    pair_id
 6       1
 8       2
 5       3
 10      4
 7       1
 9       2
 11      3
 12      4
```

Comment: This is actually an unpivot. I'll have to think on this one.

Comment: Would `UNION ALL` not work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this'd work, but try:

```
SELECT t1.id1
... snip ...
WHERE t1.id1 != t2.id1;
```

This just explicitly excludes self-overlaps, and would allow the '7' record to show up as an overlap on the '6' (as per your sample results).

Comment: ouch! yes, this is the solution...I knew should be simple, was not paying attention to the `WHERE` clause, in a couple of min will accept it

Comment: Still not accepted as I [asked in meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157966/192104) on what to do. I realized that my question should have been a little bit different, similar, but different.

Comment: Modified my question, is a (what I think to be) small variation, that's why I decided to edit instead of creating a new one.

Comment: `select t1.id1, t2.id2` would show you the ids of the overlap pairs. generating overlap ids as you in sql is posible-ish, but would be painful/ugly.

Comment: Using a mix of this answer and the one provided by @wkaha I got to my goal, thanks both

Answer (score 1):

It's a standard functionality in sql called "union"
Take a look in the documentation of the database system you are using.