# Magento php core. Editing Product List Catalog

Tags: php, database, magento, catalog

I've got a quick questions for magento experts. I would like to make changes on the PHP core of magento.

I want to add details on product listings, the details will depends on each product, and I want to display the extra details on the catalog list, so it involves the database & PHP.

So my questions is - where can do this? I am not familiar with the magento file structure and I need this rush, I hope I'll have time to study its structure but it will probably take more time than my deadline.

**Take note that I am talking about the admin product list, not the customer carting.**

Comment: You'd probably need to override the product grid class and add a column in prepareColumns() and possibly add your info to the collection in prepareCollection(). More specific info is need for a better answer.

Comment: ok thanks for the answer russjman. To give more info, I would like to add border or background color for each product listings, the color will depends what category the product belongs to. I searched & found out that the best way to do this is make a custom module, unless there are already an existing module which i doubt. But it will probably take more time, so I decided to temporarily edit the core php code for the moment. So does anyone know what php file I should look into?

Comment: Ok. What i mentioned above is for the admin section.  You can probably do all of that logic in <theme>/template/catalog/product/view.phtml, if is the detail page. If its the category page it would be <theme>/template/catalog/product/list.phtml.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do all of that logic in /template/catalog/product/view.phtml, if is the detail page. If its the category page it would be /template/catalog/product/list.phtml.  Either way it would be the same.

```
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds();  //this is array of category ids the product exists in

$blueCategoryIds = array(1,2,3,4);  
$redCategoryIds = array(5,6,7,8);

if(in_array($blueCategoryIds,$categories)){
    $newClass = 'blue-background';
} elseif (in_array($redCategoryIds,$categories)) {
    $newClass = 'red-background';
} else {
    $newClass='';
}
```

Define .blue-background and .red-background in a CSS file.

```
.red-background {background:red;}
.blue-background {background:blue;}
```

Then use $newClass in what ever html element you want to apply your background to. This probably should be part of a custom module a method, but this should you going quick.

Comment: is this on the admin page? because I intend to change on the admin page only. thank you

Comment: Unfortunately the admin grid is a completely different animal, and would require a different solution. Maybe this might work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766173/magento-different-background-color-for-group-of-rows-on-backend-grid

Comment: looks like what im looking for, thanks a lot, will be checking on it.